# Differentiability of multivariables function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have:

$f(x,y)= x^2+ln(y)$

My question is:

> To know if it is differentiable, do I need to make partial derivatives
>   and study their continuity?

Comment: Take the partials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the sufficient condition which is usually checked. It all comes down to the fact that if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ has continuous partials in a neighborhood of a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then we can define it's linearization,

\begin{align*} L(\textbf{x}) = f(p) + \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} (p) (x^j-p^j)  = f(p) + \nabla f(p)(\textbf{x}-p)\end{align*}

where $\textbf{x} = (x^1,...,x^n)$ and $p = (p^1,...,p^n)$. By chain rule, it follows that $L(\textbf{x}) \approx f(\textbf{x})$ where $\textbf{x}$ is sufficiently close to $p$ i.e $\nabla f(p) = f'(p)$ since by our remark,

$$\lim_{\textbf{x} \to p} \frac{\|f(\textbf{x})-f(p) - \nabla f(p)(\textbf{x}-p)\|}{\|\textbf{x}-p\|} = 0$$

which is the definition of the derivative.

$\textbf{Update}$: Compute the partials through the limit definition. I'll start you off with the set-up for the first,

\begin{align*} f_x(x,y) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h} \\ \\ & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^2 + \ln(y) - x^2 - \ln(y)}{h} \\ \\ & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^2 - x^2}{h} \\ \\ & = 2x\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for answering. So, is my function differentiable when y>0?

Comment: Yes. It will be. Notice that if you apply the definition for $f_x$ and $f_y$, the result will follow since $x^2$, $\ln(y)$ are differentiable. Check this to make sure you see what I mean.